# Highlighting importance of order when using short-circuited conditions

Tags: code-quality, clean-code, code-formatting, groovy, if-statement

I was working on a piece of code when I noticed that an `if` statement could work or crash depending on the order used for the parts connected with `and`.

You can replicate the problem like this:

```
boolean func(String x) {
    assert x
    return true
}
v = "text"

if (v != "" && func(v)) {
   println("Hello")
}
```

Depending on whether `v != ""` or `func(v)` is used first, the `if` causes an assertion error or not.

This is because groovy checks the first expression and if that one is already false it does not even evaluate the second as the *and operator* will always cause the expression to be false.

So in groovy the connected condition are combined like this:

```
if (v != "") {
    if (func(v)) {
        *[...]*
    }
}
```

I know that at least some other languages have a similar  behavior (I believe in Java you can switch it by using `&` or `&&`) but I ask myself is this really the way to go. It seems quite unintuitive to understand and I don't think it conveys the importance of the order in this statement.

How can I make it clear on a code basis that the order is important and should be considered when altering code around it? Or should I just forget about it and assume that people check for something like that?

---

Upon doing further research I discovered an entry on the basic groovy documentation site for operators: [Groovy - Short Circuiting](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_short_circuiting)

The general term seems to describe this seems to be 'short-circuit evaluation'. Very appropriate.
I adapted the title of the question as I wanted to put it in there but didn't know the terminology.

Comment: Your fellow programmers who are adept at the programming language you are using *already understand* that "order is important" in this context.

Comment: The "short-circuit" `&&  or ||`  is a very common idiom and it should be clear to other coders.  The non-short-circuit `&` ("long circuits?") are unusual and you might want to comment why you want to force evaluation of both sides.

Comment: The answer is in your own question: you highlighted the importance of order by nesting  conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why ?

In C, C++, Python, Java, C#, Groowy, and Swift (historical order of appearance), and certainly in many other languages as well, the usual logical and-operator (mostly `&&`) works with short-circuits.

In some languages such as ADA (i.e. `and`), the short-circuit form requires an extra effort (i.e. `and then`, which gives a little look like your successively embedded `if`-statements).

The reason of this behavior is...  short circuit, to avoid fatal failures without a lots of additional statements. Language designers have carefully evaluated the pros and cons:

> Expressions connected bu && and || are evaluated left to right, and
>   evaluation stops as soon as the truth or falsehood of the result is
>   known. **These properties are critical for writing programs that work.**
>  
>   - B.W.Kernighan & D.Ritchie, 1978, The C programming language, P.38

For example, the follwing statement works in all cases :

```
int a=10, b=0; 
if (b!=0 && a/b>3)   // ok
    ...
```

If the `and` connector would be without short circuit, such precautions would be useless:  both terms would be evaluated and the `a/b` would trigger a fatal divide by 0 exception...

```
if (b!=0 & a/b>3)   // ouch !!! 
    ...
```

### Do you need to worry ?

The world is made of two kinds of programmers:  those who are aware of the short-circuit and the order,  and those who are **not yet**.

So  don't worry, most of your peers will take care of the order.  If you fear that someone might miss something important, just put a comment :

```
if (b!=0 && a/b>3)   // order avoids divide by zero
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`&&` and `||` at least in java (and I guess in groovy as well) mean that the operation is short-circuited, i.e. as you said the right hand side will be evaluated if and only if it's necessary.

`&` and `|` evaluate both sides.

So if you're using `&&` or `||`, it already means that the order is important. In your example, using `&&` implies that `func(v)` can be evaluated only if `v != ""` is true.

Comment: It _really_ needs to be noted that both sides are evaluated because it is a bitwise operation, not a logical operator when using booleans.  so `1 | 0` evaluates to `1` which is only then treated _logically_ as `True`.  `1 || 0` on the other hand is treated as `True ∧ False` which evaluates to `True` (and yes, short circuits as soon as the answer is known)